# Elasticsearch ScrollApi - Get current scoll position

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Im using Elasticseach ScrollApi on C# (NEST) to load a large amount of data. When i restart my service while scrolling it starts where i stopped the service. As long as i use the same scrollId.

But is there a way to get the current scroll position (page) out of ES to find the current progress of the scroll?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the current scroll position from Elasticsearch as far as I know.

Each response to a scroll request returns x number of hits and also the total hits so it's possible to keep track of hits out of total hits have been scrolled so far. Bear in mind also that the `scroll_id` may change on scroll requests, so only the most recent `scroll_id` returned should be used.

You may be interested in [`search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-search-after.html) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've implemented a persistent layer to store the progress by myself. search_after is no option for me because the sort order may change depending on update and delete requests.

Comment: yep, that's one thing to bear in mind with `search_after`. On the flip side, it's ideal if you need to do deep pagination.